# Use map function to transform two seqs into one. Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

in clojure we have a map function where you can provide a function and two collections

```
(map + [1 2 ] [4 5 ]) ;;=> (5 7 )
```

is there something similar in Scala?

I tried with for comprehension but then i got 4 combinations.

If there is a way with for comprehension, would be even better because i have to do some filtering in the future/

Comment: In most languages, this is just a zip operation,combined with a map. It's just handy that Clojure kind of gave `map`s a zipping behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.zip` first to combine the two collections into one, then map:

```
seq1.zip(seq2).map { case (x, y) => x + y }
```

I don't think it's possible with a for-comprehension. You can do filtering with a call to `.filter` or `.filterNot` as well.

Answer (score 1):

@JoeK gives you the specific answer.

I'll provide two more general answers for you. Clojure, and many other dynamic languages, will often abstract over arity (the standard library's `map` and `apply` functions are great examples of this). In the absence of dependent types, this is difficult to do in statically typed languages. The general pattern you'll see instead is repeated applications of a function as many times as needed. In this case if you needed to do

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])
```

You would need to do

```
xs.zip(ys).zip(zs).map{ case (x, (y, z)) => x + y + z }
```

Generally this extra boilerplate is not terrible. Where abstraction over arity becomes more sorely missed is when you want to abstract over arbitrary tuples or arbitrary case classes. That's when [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), a Scala library that gives you a limited form of dependent types, comes into play.

I would not break out Shapeless for something like this though.

The second general point is that you cannot zip lists in the manner you're asking for with for comprehensions (well not in general... because you can compare everything for equality in Scala you kind of sort of can with a final filter pass but that fails for anything where builtin equality doesn't give you what you want). The general principle behind this is a bit more subtle. It turns out that there's a hierarchy of power of these collection functions. You start out with `map`. If you add `zip` and `List.apply` you jump to the next level. If you replace `zip` with `flatten` you get another level. With `flatten` you can recover a version of `zip`, but not the other way around.

The default Scala `flatMap` and `flatten` (note that a for comprehension is ultimately a series of `flatMap` calls) for collections does give rise to a form of `zip`, i.e. something with the same type signature, but it turns out to be the Cartesian product as you've noticed.

There is a version of `flatten` that does give rise to the standard `zip`, but it only makes sense if all your collections are the same length. It involves taking the diagonal of the square matrix that results from a collection of collections.

This is usually not as useful for finite collections because Scala's type system is not powerful enough to express the constant length constraint and you can get some strange behavior if you don't ensure consistent length.

On the other hand this is the version of `flatten` and `flatMap` that is actually useful for infinite streams (where the equivalent of `List.apply` is an infinite constant stream) whereas the "normal" version of `flatten` would fail to get past processing the first stream.

Side note: You can of course always use your zipped list later in a for comprehension (where you might do some filtering). You just can't implement the zipping itself in a for comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Not really adding anything new here, but maybe this will help:

```
def mapCollections[A,B,C](as: Seq[A], bs: Seq[B])(f: (A,B) => C): Seq[C] = 
  as zip bs map f.tupled

mapCollections(List(1, 2), List(4, 5))(_ + _) // = List(5, 7)
```